# just trying to read xml fragment and change some things

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read in this xml fragment and change attr2's name and value, and leave everything else the way it is.

How do I read and write the other elements as-is in my else clause below? Also, if there is a better way to do this, I welcome the ideas!

```
string xmlFragment = @"
    <blah>...</blah>
    <more attr='blah' />
    <fragment attr1='value1' />
    <fragment attr2='value2' attr3='value3' />
    ";

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlFragment), settings))
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "fragment")
        {
            if (reader.GetAttribute("attr2") != null)
            {
                //change this element
                string test = reader.GetAttribute("attr2");
                sw.Write("<fragment attr2Upd='value2Upd' attr3='value3' />");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //copy the element the way it is.
            //how do I copy the current element to StreamWriter as-is
        }
    }

    sw.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string test = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the node based on node type:

```
switch (reader.NodeType) {
      case XmlNodeType.Element:
          sw.Write(string.Format("<{0}>", reader.Name));
          break;
      case XmlNodeType.Text:
          sw.Write(reader.Value);
          break;
       case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
           sw.Write(string.Format("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", reader.Value));
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
           sw.Write(string.Format("<?{0} {1}?>", reader.Name, reader.Value));
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.Comment:
           sw.Write(string.Format("<!--{0}-->", reader.Value));
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
           sw.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.Document:
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
           sw.Write(string.Format("<!DOCTYPE {0} [{1}]", reader.Name, reader.Value));
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
           sw.Write(reader.Name);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
           sw.Write(string.Format("</{0}>", reader.Name));
           break;
   }
```

Reference: [MSDN - XmlReader.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)